# I'm getting error when I want to update

Tags: updates

I'm new Ubuntu user. I'm getting error, when I type `sudo apt-get update`. My terminal is like this:

```
Hit:1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease   
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease       
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease        
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu impish InRelease 
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ebupd8team/java`

Comment: Thanks, It's working properly now. Thanks again.